# Why does openssl_pkey_new() fail?

Tags: php, windows, openssl, xampp

I'm very new to this. Why is `openssl_pkey_new()` returning false?

I am using XAMPP and there is a an OpenSSL under the `Apahce\bin` directory.

What obvious beginner mistake am I making?  Maybe it's a matter of SSL configuration?

My goal is to write the two keys into two files.

---

***Update***: as suggested, I used `openssl_error_string()` and it says `error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process`. It sounds like maybe OpenSSL isn't running or isn't in the path??  Any ideas?

---

***Update***: I put `c:\xampp\php` into the windows path, so that it could find `libeay32.dll`and restarted Apache.

Now I get `error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file`.  Any ideas?

Comment: some basic check - http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558321/openssl-not-working-on-windows

Comment: Possible duplicates: [OpenSSL and error in reading openssl.conf file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7360602)  and [Xampp openssl errors when calling openssl_pkey_new()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4719939).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`openssl_error_string()`](http://php.net/openssl_error_string) to find out why `openssl_pkey_new()` is returning false (or any other OpenSSL error).

---

After your latest update, it appears that OpenSSL can't find the `openssl.cnf` file, as [described here](http://au.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php).

Comment: for my case, i copied from C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf to C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL\openssl.cnf or C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\SSL\openssl.cnf works.

Answer (score 0):

**For me with XAMPP on Windows 10 it works:**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869750/4695499. (You can find exactly those steps in the old Control panel in Windows 10 under one of the display options)
2. I also tried uncomment `extension=php_openssl.dll` in **php.ini** (but I mean it’s working without that)
3. I restarted computer and Apache, then `openssl_pkey_new()` generated some of `RESOURCE` instead of `false`

Comment: Thanks, Star. After 15 years or more, I finally dropped Xampp and installed Apache, PHP & MySql. Surprisingly easy to do and, finally, I feel like  pro ;-) Since it has been 11 years since I asked this question, I can't even remember it, let alone reproduce it, but thank you for posting your answer. I hope that it will help others who post here in future (upvote)