# xampp openssl errors when calling openssl_pkey_new();

Tags: php, windows, openssl, xampp

so I am trying to get openssl working on my windows installation of xampp(1.7.3) which is built with OpenSSL 0.9.8l. This is only my second time to install openssl on an *amp install but the first time went swimmingly(it was a wamp install on the same machine, but I found that xampp was more my style so I switched).

when I attempted a simple setup script:

```
var_dump(getenv('OPENSSL_CONF'));
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new();

while($message = openssl_error_string()){
    echo $message.'<br />'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

I got a returned message:

```
error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file  
error:0E064002:configuration file routines:CONF_load:system lib
```

I read the php.net page that informed me about the possibility of needing to set the openssl.cnf and ssleay.dll environment constants, I tried that but nothing changed.

A `var_dump` of `OPENSSL_CONF` resulted in the path: `C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf` which is correct for my machine.

I checked that the path to the php directory (where ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll are located) was defined in my path system var, and it was not, so I defined it, restarted my machine, and in the process rebooted apache, but no change in the error messages.

my version of xampp did not come with a php_openssl.dll and as such I believe the php.ini document should exclude it from the list of available .dlls as it did when I checked. I believe xampp comes compiles with a zend based extension instead.

I am able to start openssl from the xampp gui, and I sucessfully created a private/public key pair.

phpinfo() reports:

> openssl OpenSSL support  enabled
>   OpenSSL Library Version  OpenSSL
>   0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009 OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009

there was an old ssleay.dll and libeay32.dll from the wamp install I presume in my systems directory but I have deleted them since. (restarted after, and rebooted apache)

I tried copying the openssl.cnf to the default directory'C:\usr\local\ssl\openssl.cnf' no change.

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290111/how-to-install-test-openssl-on-xampp-windows) thread and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282507/why-does-openssl-pkey-new-fail) thread but the answers given were relevant but failed to help or were non-existant.

Anyone have any ideas on what I should check next or anything obvious that I missed?

Comment: Its interesting `OPENSSL_CONF` is `C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf`, which is well configured. The only minor nit is Windows uses back slashes, not forward slashes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you need to specify the path to your `openssl.cnf` file when calling [`openssl_pkey_new()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php):

```
$configArgs = array(
    'config' => '/etc/openssl/openssl.cnf',
    // ...
);
openssl_pkey_new($configArgs);
```

You may also need to specify additional settings in `$configArgs` for the function to work (have not tested that lately).
See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-new.php for a description of supported further configuration arguments.

Comment: ok I can give it a try, I thought that the function should look for the openssl.cnf file based on the routing specified on http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php, but maybe it doesnt have access to the environment var?

Comment: where is the location of openssl.cnf

Comment: It depends on your OpenSSL installation. If you use OpenSSL from a Linux system with package management, it may be in `/etc/openssl/` as in the example. You may find a web server environment variable `$_SERVER['OPENSSL_CONF']` that gives you the location.

Comment: Worked for me only after I set explicitly $configArgs['config'] to getenv('OPENSSL_CONF'). It seems that openssl_pkey_new is ignoring the env variable and requires you set the configuration explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

You check the OPENSSL_CONF variable in xampp/apache/conf/extra/http-xampp.conf

Then start apache using the xampp/apache_start.bat NOT THE XAMPP CONTROL PANEL (its strange that when started from the control panel it doesn't work [maybe a current directory problem])

This is for XAMPP 1.7.4 on Win7 64bit