# X.509: Private / Public Key

Tags: openssl, x509, private-key, public-key

We're trying to implement some functionality of a Web-Service from one of our partners. Now, the content which is beeing transmitted, should be encrypted with a public key, which we have to provide.

The security-specification says that the public-certificate has to be X.509 standard. Doesn't X.509 rely on the private / public key method? Because I only get one .pem file, containing a private key, and a certificate, but no public key, using the following command:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out ./cert.pem -keyout ./cert.pem
```

Do I have to modify the command in order to create a private and a public key?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The basics command line steps to generate a private and public key using OpenSSL are as follow

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 1024
openssl req -new -x509 -key private.key -out publickey.cer -days 365
openssl pkcs12 -export -out public_privatekey.pfx -inkey private.key -in publickey.cer
```

Step 1 – generates a private key

Step 2 – creates a X509 certificate (.cer file) containing your public key which you upload when registering your private application (or upgrading to a partner application).

Step 3 – Export your x509 certificate and private key to a pfx file. If your chosen wrapper library uses the .pem file to sign requests then this step is not required.

[This answer explains](https://serverfault.com/a/9717/179158) the different file extensions.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the 3rd command does, but it seems to work quite nicely with the privatekey.pem and the publickey.cer. Thanks!

Comment: In this example, does `privatekey.pem` contain just the private key or the public key as well?

Comment: You are using the wrong file extension in your first command. You should use `.key` instead of `.pem`, to avoid confusion. The resulting file will be simply a private key. Someone might send the `.pem` file to someone else by mistake, creating a security problem.

Comment: I've spent so much time reading articles and posts trying to generate a .PFX file so I can utilize it for SAML single sign on. Your second line of code was the silver bullet - I haven't seen anyone mention using the -x509 argument. Everyone has it generating the CSR which I don't need my cert signed in this case.

Comment: For other users:
If some error if config, follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360602/openssl-and-error-in-reading-openssl-conf-file

Answer (score 16):

Public key is stored inside of x.509 certificate.
Certificate binds identity information (common name, address, whatever else) to this public key.

Comment: Well, in my case there is a **BEGIN CERTIFICATE** and a **BEGIN PRIVATE KEY**. Is the CERTIFICATE my public key? And can I split those two into seperate files, so the other side doesn't get to see the private key?

Comment: Yes, CERTIFICATE part is the certificate (base64-encoded, with public key), PRIVATE KEY - is, doh, the private key. You can (and actually SHOULD) separate them and send only certificate part to other party.

Comment: Ok, thank you alot. I'll send them the CERTIFICATE part then :) I'd like to upvote, but obviously I reached my daily vote limit :O

Answer (score 8):

Create a private-public key pair.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out public.cert -days 365
```

Optionally, combine the pair into a single file.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private.key -in public.cert -out certificate.pfx
```

This results in the following files.

```
private.key
certificate.pfx
public.cert
```

See also

- https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/req.html
- https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/pkcs12.html
- https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file