# X509 certificate for Google Cloud HSM

Tags: java, security, google-cloud-platform, openssl, keytool

I want to generate an X509 certificate for a private key stored in the Google Cloud HSM.

Using Java Key tool and a local Java "keystore" i would do something like this:

> keytool -exportcert -alias sign1 -keystore signkeystore -storetype jks
> -storepass password -file sign1.certificate

See http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-cryptography/keytool.html

Using OpenSSL i would do something like this:

> openssl genrsa -out private.key 1024
>
> openssl req -new -x509 -key private.key -out publickey.cer -days 365
>
> openssl pkcs12 -export -out public_privatekey.pfx -inkey private.key -in publickey.cer

See [X.509: Private / Public Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480846/x-509-private-public-key)

It would seem, generating a certificate needs access to *the "private key"*, in some fashion, either directly like OpenSSL or indirectly like *keytool* using the private keystore.

Gcloud documentation seems to use OpenSSL for generating the private key. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates

How do i get a X509 certificate for a private key in Google Cloud HSM. Has anyone done this before ?

Regards
Suchak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at this thread [Creating an X509 Certificate in Java without BouncyCastle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615871/creating-an-x509-certificate-in-java-without-bouncycastle).

Then I did the following two create a GCloud X509 Certificate

1. Create a key in the GCloud HSM (see https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/hsm)
2. Download the public key from GCloud.
3. Use the code below to create a X509 certificate.
4. Run some unit tests on the same.

```
    /**
     * Create a self-signed X.509 based on a public key
     * @param googlePublicKey the Public key downloaded from Google Cloud HSM
     * @param dn        the X.509 Distinguished Name, eg "CN=Test, L=London, C=GB"
     * @param days      how many days from now the Example is valid for
     * @param algorithm the signing algorithm, eg "SHA1withRSA"
     */
    public static X509Certificate generateRSACertificate(String googlePublicKey, String dn, int days, String algorithm)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        byte[] derKey = Base64.decodeBase64(googlePublicKey);
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(derKey);
        PublicKey rsaKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(keySpec);
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privkey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        X509CertInfo info = new X509CertInfo();
        Date from = new Date();
        Date to = new Date(from.getTime() + days * 86400000l);
        CertificateValidity interval = new CertificateValidity(from, to);
        BigInteger sn = new BigInteger(64, new SecureRandom());
        X500Name owner = new X500Name(dn);

        info.set(X509CertInfo.VALIDITY, interval);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.SERIAL_NUMBER, new CertificateSerialNumber(sn));
        info.set(X509CertInfo.SUBJECT, owner);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, owner);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.KEY, new CertificateX509Key(rsaKey));
        info.set(X509CertInfo.VERSION, new CertificateVersion(CertificateVersion.V3));
        AlgorithmId algo = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.md5WithRSAEncryption_oid);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.ALGORITHM_ID, new CertificateAlgorithmId(algo));

        // Sign the cert to identify the algorithm that's used.
        X509CertImpl cert = new X509CertImpl(info);
        cert.sign(privkey, algorithm);

        // Update the algorith, and resign.
        algo = (AlgorithmId) cert.get(X509CertImpl.SIG_ALG);
        info.set(CertificateAlgorithmId.NAME + "." + CertificateAlgorithmId.ALGORITHM, algo);
        cert = new X509CertImpl(info);
        cert.sign(privkey, algorithm);
        return cert;
    }
```

Imports used were

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import sun.security.x509.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
```