# 'openssl' is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: windows, cmd, openssl

I am trying to execute the following command in command prompt .

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "<path-to-users-directory>\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

But the command prompt windows reports:

```
'openssl' is not recognized as internal or external command.
```

What ca I do to execute this command in command prompt window?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

install openssl for windows from the following link .

https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip

Comment: I have downloaded openssl for windows from here . https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip

But I dnt see any .exe file to set up . Only there are bin , lib and include folder .

Comment: try to download binary file of openSSL

Comment: Hi, I am downloaded the openSSL zip file and extracted it but I am not able to find any .exe file.

Comment: @Deepak bin/openssl.exe

Answer (score 37):

The error you saw means there's no such program in your `%PATH%` (external command) and it's also not a built-in shell command (internal command).

Install OpenSSL on your machine. You will also need to check that its installed location is in your `%PATH%`. By default it probably won't be. As an example,  suppose OpenSSL is installed at `c:\OpenSSL-Win32`. The `openssl` binary is probably located at `c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe`. So you path needs to include `c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin`.

Sometimes OpenSSL cannot find its configuration file on Windows. For that, see [OpenSSL and error in reading openssl.conf file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7360602/608639).

---

Another option is to use the full path in the command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "<path-to-users-directory>\.android\debug.keystore" | ^
  c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe base64
```

However, this still suffers the OpenSSL configuration file problem detailed at [OpenSSL and error in reading openssl.conf file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7360602/608639).

Comment: what is the path address to set up ?

Comment: This really helped me out.

Comment: it was useful for me. thank you

Answer (score 22):

Just you need to Add OpenSSL bin path (ex: C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin) to  the PATH system variable as shown below:

[image]

Comment: If you are going the route of using the OpenSSL that comes with git bash, the bath is just `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to: https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads
2. Extract file
3. open bin/openssl.exe

Answer (score -6):

Install openssl on your Windows machine.