# subprocess.run() produces different result than manual input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run the following Windows console commands through a Python script:

`C:\My\Path\openssl.exe x509 -in C:\My\PEM\mypem.pem -noout -subject > C:\My\Data\data.txt`

If put directly into the console, produces the expected 1KB file.

Using `subprocess.run()` does not. It produces a file, but a 0KB file as if it is not grabbing the `stdout` response.

What I've tried without success:

```
# produces b''
args = 'C:/My/Path/openssl.exe x509 -in C:/My/PEM/mypem.pem -noout -subject'
data = subprocess.check_output(args)
print (data)

# produces b''
result = subprocess.Popen('C:/My/Path/openssl.exe x509 -in C:/My/PEM/mypem.pem -noout -subject', stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
print (result.stdout) 

# produces a 0KB data.txt
# probably also producing a b'' thus the 0KB
subprocess.run('C:/My/Path/openssl.exe x509 -in C:/My/PEM/mypem.pem -noout -subject > C:/My/Data/data.txt')
```

Comment: Try capturing the `stderr` and see if it's reporting an error.

Comment: @Barmar Just used `subprocess.PIPE` for both `stderr` and `stdout` and both yield `b''`.

Comment: You are using shell redirection (the `>`) and are not running with `shell=True`. Instead, you use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to redirect the output to the Python process. You could as well read the output and write the file yourself.

Comment: @9000 That is what I have been trying to do. So even if I drop the `> ...` and just run up through `-subject` the returned value is always `b''` so I cant write to the file since there is nothing to write.

Comment: Why not use pyOpenSSL? it has almost the same capabilities

Comment: @Dalvenjia external modules unavailable in our workspace

Comment: Of *course* there's nothing to write if you manage to successfully perform a redirection with `>` -- you're sending your output to a file, so nothing goes to the pipeline. (On UNIX, that'll only happen with `shell=True`, but this looks like Windows, and the way command execution works on Windows is far more convoluted).

Comment: (..on which point, you should **really** specify the platform in the question -- your code here is not at all portable; on UNIX, none of the commands given would work at all without `shell=True`).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `shell=True` if you want the string parsed as a command with arguments.

```
result = subprocess.Popen('C:/My/Path/openssl.exe x509 -in C:/My/PEM/mypem.pem -noout -subject', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

Or you can specify the command as a list:

```
result = subprocess.Popen(['C:/My/Path/openssl.exe', 'x509', '-in', 'C:/My/PEM/mypem.pem', '-noout', '-subject'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: That should be `stdout=open('data.txt', 'w')` to provide parity with the original `>data.txt`, no?

Comment: My answer is based on his first code with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.

Comment: @Barmar both methods still produce `b''` as if the `stdout` has no data. If I copy the exact same command directly into a command terminal, it executes without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is my solution:

It is unclear to me absolutely why this is an issue, but I am hypothesizing that OpenSSL must be one shell, then x509 is another shell opened inside OpenSSL and this creates an issue on Windows using `subprocess`, but not Linux.

You can type separately and sequentially on the CMDline `OpenSSL` and then `x509` to get an idea of what I am talking about. To solve this, I opened up the supposed OpenSSL and x509 shell in one `subprocess` command then fed the rest of the required data into the process's stdin using a `subprocess.PIPE`. Here is an example of my program, I am sure you could modify in yours to make this work:

```
p=subprocess.Popen("openssl x509 -in " + VARS["CLIENTCERT"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
aissuer = p.communicate(bytes("-noout -issuer -nameopt multiline,-align,-esc_msb,utf8,-space_eq;", "utf-8"))[0].decode().strip("\n") # gets stdout
```

Keep in mind, if you want to run on UNIX and Windows, you should be specifying two commands and running them based on what `os.name` returns (e.g., nt for Windows...)

Also, you should be setting OpenSSL to your PATH variable so you don't have to specify a path for OpenSSL. To do so, check out Ahmed's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838516/openssl-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command/56414041#56414041).