# Static compile Qt 5.13.1 with -openssl-linked using MinGW (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, openssl, qmake

Re: [Static compilation. Qt 5.12.3](https://forum.qt.io/topic/107364/static-compile-qt-5-13-1-with-openssl-1-1-1d-using-mingw-in-windows-10)

Good day

*Qt Forum suggested I create a new post as the linked one is 'quite old'*

This essentially serves as a confirmation of some 'bug', what the exact problem is I am not sure, but I can simply provide you with my compile script and the error.

The purpose is to compile OpenSSL against Qt, which will allow me to compile a single all-in-one binary application I can ship. I was able to achieve [this but had inconsistency issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188129/statically-compiled-qt-5-13-1-with-openssl-1-1-1d-producing-qsslsocketconnectt), thus bringing me back to the recompilation side.

**The error compilation line repeating is shown below:**

```
..\..\..\..\include\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport\5.13.1/QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport/private/qwindowsuiawrapper_p.h:1:10: fatal error: ../../../../../src/platformsupport/windowsuiautomation/qwindowsuiawrapper_p.h: No such file or directory
 #include "../../../../../src/platformsupport/windowsuiautomation/qwindowsuiawrapper_p.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

**Question:**

How can I statically compile Qt with OpenSSL using the `-openssl-linked` configuration flag?

---

**Further additional details below:**
My Setup Environment:

- Using MinGW32 for compilation

  - Using OpenSSL 1.1.1d precompiled downloadable from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), *it has MinGW libs which I link to, shown further down in the post*.
- `PATH` has the OpenSSL `/bin`  added with version `OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019`

The script I am using to compile Qt can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/hWfZDm8z), provided by Qt on [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW) page. For the addition of OpenSSL, I am using [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Compiling_OpenSSL_with_MinGW) as a guide.

My compile scirpt configuration is:

```
    $QtSrcUrl = "F:\Qt\Static-OpenSSL-Linked\src\qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1.tar",
    $QtStaticDir = "F:\Qt\Static-OpenSSL-Linked",
    $QtVersion = "",
    $arch = "32",
    $MingwDir = "",
    $threads = "16",
    $OPENSSL_HOME = "C:\OpenSSL\OpenSSL-Win$($arch)",

    set OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto"
    cmd /c "configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -prefix $QtDir `
        -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -sql-sqlite -openssl-linked -I $($OPENSSL_HOME)\include -L$($OPENSSL_HOME)\lib\MinGW `
        -opensource -confirm-license `
        -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests"
    cmd /c "mingw32-make -k -j$($threads)"
```

I already have OpenSSL installed at

```
PS C:\OpenSSL\OpenSSL-Win32> ls

Directory: C:\OpenSSL\OpenSSL-Win32

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2019/09/30     07:27                bin
d-----       2019/09/30     07:27                exp
d-----       2019/09/30     07:27                include
d-----       2019/09/30     07:27                lib
d-----       2019/09/30     07:27                tests
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10             89 acknowledgements.txt
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10            752 authors.txt
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10         596279 changes.txt
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10           6408 c_rehash.pl
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10             86 faq.txt
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10        2515456 libcrypto-1_1.dll
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10         530432 libssl-1_1.dll
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10           6246 license.txt
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10          43136 news.txt
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10           3251 readme.txt
-a----       2019/09/30     07:27          96904 unins000.dat
-a----       2019/09/30     07:26         730789 unins000.exe
```

I saw some posts refering to `%OPENSSL_HOME%` and `%OPENSSL_HOME%\libs` and using an env variable set as

```
OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto"
```

which I tried, but always complained that "-lssl" could not be found. Thus I opted for the following dir, and it appeared to work correctly and picked up `-lssl -lcrypto` (not sure if this may be an accomplice with the compilation issue).

```
PS C:\OpenSSL\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\MinGW> ls

    Directory: C:\OpenSSL\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\MinGW

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2019/09/11     18:11        3347286 libcrypto.a
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10         109020 libcrypto.def
-a----       2019/09/11     18:11         385126 libssl.a
-a----       2019/09/11     18:10          14033 libssl.def
```

**Configuration Summary:** (the important bit)

```
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... no
  IPv6 ifname ............................ no
  libproxy ............................... no
  Schannel ............................... no
  OpenSSL ................................ yes
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ yes
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ yes
  DTLS ................................... yes
  OCSP-stapling .......................... yes
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
```

Further examples of the error line can be seen below:

```
In file included from uiautomation\qwindowsuiabaseprovider.h:50:0,
                 from uiautomation\qwindowsuiabaseprovider.cpp:43:
..\..\..\..\include\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport\5.13.1/QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport/private/qwindowsuiawrapper_p.h:1:10: fatal error: ../../../../../src/platformsupport/windowsuiautomation/qwindowsuiawrapper_p.h: No such file or directory
 #include "../../../../../src/platformsupport/windowsuiautomation/qwindowsuiawrapper_p.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[6]: *** [Makefile.Debug:11357: .obj/debug/qwindowsuiabaseprovider.o] Error 1
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -Og -std=c++1z -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -Wextra -Wvla -Wdate-time -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wno-stringop-overflow -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_STATIC_BUILD -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DLIBEGL_NAME=libEGL -DLIBGLESV2_NAME=libGLESv2 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_STATICPLUGIN -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_EVENTDISPATCHER_SUPPORT_LIB -DQT_FONTDATABASE_SUPPORT_LIB -DQT_THEME_SUPPORT_LIB -DQT_ACCESSIBILITY_SUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WINDOWSUIAUTOMATION_SUPPORT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_PLUGIN_RESOURCE_INIT_FUNCTION=qwindowsd_plugin_resource_init -I. -I. -I..\..\..\3rdparty\wintab -I..\..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\..\include\QtEventDispatcherSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtEventDispatcherSupport\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtEventDispatcherSupport\5.13.1\QtEventDispatcherSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtFontDatabaseSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtFontDatabaseSupport\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtFontDatabaseSupport\5.13.1\QtFontDatabaseSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtThemeSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtThemeSupport\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtThemeSupport\5.13.1\QtThemeSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtAccessibilitySupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtAccessibilitySupport\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtAccessibilitySupport\5.13.1\QtAccessibilitySupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport\5.13.1\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtGui\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtGui\5.13.1\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\include\QtCore\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtCore\5.13.1\QtCore -I..\..\..\..\include\QtCore -I.moc\debug -IC:\OpenSSL\OpenSSL-Win32\include -I..\..\..\..\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o .obj\debug\qwindowsuiavalueprovider.o uiautomation\qwindowsuiavalueprovider.cpp
```

and another example

```
In file included from ..\windows\uiautomation\qwindowsuiabaseprovider.h:50:0,
                 from ..\windows\uiautomation\qwindowsuiagriditemprovider.h:46,
                 from ..\windows\uiautomation\qwindowsuiagriditemprovider.cpp:43:
..\..\..\..\include\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport\5.13.1/QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport/private/qwindowsuiawrapper_p.h:1:10: fatal error: ../../../../../src/platformsupport/windowsuiautomation/qwindowsuiawrapper_p.h: No such file or directory
 #include "../../../../../src/platformsupport/windowsuiautomation/qwindowsuiawrapper_p.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[6]: *** [Makefile.Debug:14323: .obj/debug/qwindowsuiagriditemprovider.o] Error 1
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -Og -std=c++1z -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -Wextra -Wvla -Wdate-time -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wno-stringop-overflow -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_STATIC_BUILD -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DLIBEGL_NAME=libEGL -DLIBGLESV2_NAME=libGLESv2 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_STATICPLUGIN -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_EVENTDISPATCHER_SUPPORT_LIB -DQT_FONTDATABASE_SUPPORT_LIB -DQT_THEME_SUPPORT_LIB -DQT_ACCESSIBILITY_SUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WINDOWSUIAUTOMATION_SUPPORT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_PLUGIN_RESOURCE_INIT_FUNCTION=qdirect2dd_plugin_resource_init -I. -I..\windows -I..\..\..\3rdparty\wintab -I..\..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\..\include\QtEventDispatcherSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtEventDispatcherSupport\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtEventDispatcherSupport\5.13.1\QtEventDispatcherSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtFontDatabaseSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtFontDatabaseSupport\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtFontDatabaseSupport\5.13.1\QtFontDatabaseSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtThemeSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtThemeSupport\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtThemeSupport\5.13.1\QtThemeSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtAccessibilitySupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtAccessibilitySupport\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtAccessibilitySupport\5.13.1\QtAccessibilitySupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport\5.13.1\QtWindowsUIAutomationSupport -I..\..\..\..\include\QtGui\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtGui\5.13.1\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\include\QtCore\5.13.1 -I..\..\..\..\include\QtCore\5.13.1\QtCore -I..\..\..\..\include\QtCore -I.moc\debug -IC:\OpenSSL\OpenSSL-Win32\include -I..\..\..\..\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o .obj\debug\qwindowsuiawindowprovider.o ..\windows\uiautomation\qwindowsuiawindowprovider.cpp
```

The last few lines before compilation completion, I have this:

```
F:\Qt\Static-OpenSSL-Linked\src\qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe -install qinstall F:\Qt\Static-OpenSSL-Linked\src\qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1\qtbase\mkspecs\winrt-x86-msvc2017 F:\Qt\Static-OpenSSL-Linked\5.13.1_x32\mkspecs\winrt-x86-msvc2017
F:\Qt\Static-OpenSSL-Linked\src\qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe -install qinstall F:\Qt\Static-OpenSSL-Linked\src\qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1\qtbase\mkspecs\winrt-x86-msvc2019 F:\Qt\Static-OpenSSL-Linked\5.13.1_x32\mkspecs\winrt-x86-msvc2019
mingw32-make[1]: Target 'install' not remade because of errors.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'F:/Qt/Static-OpenSSL-Linked/src/qt-everywhere-src-5.13.1/qtbase'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:94: module-qtbase-install_subtargets] Error 2
mingw32-make: Target 'install' not remade because of errors.
```

**Configuration Summary:**

```
Build type: win32-g++ (i386, CPU features: <none>)
Compiler: gcc 7.3.0
Configuration: sse2 aesni sse3 ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 avx avx2 avx512f avx512bw avx512cd avx512dq avx512er avx512ifma avx512pf avx512vbmi avx512vl compile_examples f16c largefile optimize_debug precompile_header rdrnd shani x86SimdAlways debug_and_release release debug build_all c++11 c++14 c++1z concurrent dbus no-pkg-config release_tools static stl
Build options:
  Mode ................................... debug and release; default link: debug; optimized tools
  Optimize debug build ................... yes
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Building shared libraries .............. no
  Using C standard ....................... C11
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++17
  Generating GDB index ................... no
  Using precompiled headers .............. yes
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    SSE .................................. SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2
    AVX .................................. AVX AVX2
    AVX512 ............................... F ER CD PF DQ BW VL IFMA VBMI
    Other x86 ............................ AES F16C RDRAND SHA
    Intrinsics without -mXXX option ...... yes
  Build parts ............................ libs
  App store compliance ................... no
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... no
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... no
  udev ................................... no
  Using system zlib ...................... no
  Zstandard support ...................... no
Qt Core:
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ no
  GLib ................................... no
  iconv .................................. no
  ICU .................................... no
  Built-in copy of the MIME database ..... yes
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  Using system PCRE2 ..................... no
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... no
  IPv6 ifname ............................ no
  libproxy ............................... no
  Schannel ............................... no
  OpenSSL ................................ yes
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ yes
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ yes
  DTLS ................................... yes
  OCSP-stapling .......................... yes
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ no
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ no
  Fontconfig ............................. no
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... no
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ no
  EGL .................................... no
  OpenVG ................................. no
  OpenGL:
    ANGLE ................................ no
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... yes
    Dynamic OpenGL ....................... no
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ no
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. no
  libinput ............................... no
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. no
  tslib .................................. no
  xkbcommon .............................. no
  X11 specific:
    XLib ................................. no
    XCB Xlib ............................. no
    EGL on X11 ........................... no
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. no
  LinuxFB ................................ no
  VNC .................................... no
  Mir client ............................. no
  Windows:
    Direct 2D ............................ yes
    DirectWrite .......................... yes
    DirectWrite 2 ........................ yes
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows WindowsVista
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... no
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... yes
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes
Qt SerialBus:
  Socket CAN ............................. no
  Socket CAN FD .......................... no
  SerialPort Support ..................... yes
Further Image Formats:
  JasPer ................................. no
  MNG .................................... no
  TIFF ................................... yes
    Using system libtiff ................. no
  WEBP ................................... yes
    Using system libwebp ................. no
Qt QML:
  QML network support .................... yes
  QML debugging and profiling support .... yes
  QML tracing JIT support ................ no
  QML sequence object .................... yes
  QML list model ......................... yes
  QML XML http request ................... yes
  QML Locale ............................. yes
  QML delegate model ..................... yes
Qt Quick:
  Direct3D 12 ............................ no
  AnimatedImage item ..................... yes
  Canvas item ............................ yes
  Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes
  Flipable item .......................... yes
  GridView item .......................... yes
  ListView item .......................... yes
  TableView item ......................... yes
  Path support ........................... yes
  PathView item .......................... yes
  Positioner items ....................... yes
  Repeater item .......................... yes
  ShaderEffect item ...................... yes
  Sprite item ............................ yes
Qt Scxml:
  ECMAScript data model for QtScxml ...... yes
Qt Gamepad:
  SDL2 ................................... no
Qt 3D:
  Assimp ................................. yes
  System Assimp .......................... no
  Output Qt3D Job traces ................. no
  Output Qt3D GL traces .................. no
  Use SSE2 instructions .................. no
  Use AVX2 instructions .................. no
  Aspects:
    Render aspect ........................ yes
    Input aspect ......................... yes
    Logic aspect ......................... yes
    Animation aspect ..................... yes
    Extras aspect ........................ yes
Qt 3D Renderers:
  OpenGL Renderer ........................ yes
Qt 3D GeometryLoaders:
  Autodesk FBX ........................... no
Qt Wayland Client ........................ no
Qt Wayland Compositor .................... no
Qt Bluetooth:
  BlueZ .................................. no
  BlueZ Low Energy ....................... no
  Linux Crypto API ....................... no
  WinRT Bluetooth API (desktop & UWP) .... no
  WinRT advanced bluetooth low energy API (desktop & UWP) . no
Qt Sensors:
  sensorfw ............................... no
Qt Quick Controls 2:
  Styles ................................. Default Fusion Imagine Material Universal
Qt Quick Templates 2:
  Hover support .......................... yes
  Multi-touch support .................... yes
Qt Positioning:
  Gypsy GPS Daemon ....................... no
  WinRT Geolocation API .................. no
Qt Location:
  Qt.labs.location experimental QML plugin . yes
  Geoservice plugins:
    OpenStreetMap ........................ yes
    HERE ................................. yes
    Esri ................................. yes
    Mapbox ............................... yes
    MapboxGL ............................. yes
    Itemsoverlay ......................... yes
QtXmlPatterns:
  XML schema support ..................... yes
Qt Multimedia:
  ALSA ................................... no
  GStreamer 1.0 .......................... no
  GStreamer 0.10 ......................... no
  Video for Linux ........................ no
  OpenAL ................................. no
  PulseAudio ............................. no
  Resource Policy (libresourceqt5) ....... no
  Windows Audio Services ................. no
  DirectShow ............................. yes
  Windows Media Foundation ............... no
Qt Tools:
  QDoc ................................... no
Qt WebEngineCore:
  Qt WebEngine Widgets ................... yes
  Qt WebEngine Qml ....................... yes
  Embedded build ......................... no
  Full debug information ................. no
  Pepper Plugins ......................... yes
  Printing and PDF ....................... yes
  Proprietary Codecs ..................... no
  Spellchecker ........................... yes
  Native Spellchecker .................... no
  WebRTC ................................. yes
  Use System Ninja ....................... no
  Geolocation ............................ yes
  WebChannel support ..................... yes
  Use v8 snapshot ........................ yes
  Kerberos Authentication ................ yes
  Extensions ............................. yes
Qt WebEngineQml:
  UI Delegates ........................... yes
  Test Support ........................... no

Note: Using static linking will disable the use of dynamically
loaded plugins. Make sure to import all needed static plugins,
or compile needed modules into the library.

Note: When linking against OpenSSL, you can override the default
library names through OPENSSL_LIBS.
For example:
    OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/opt/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto' ./configure -openssl-linked

Note: No wayland-egl support detected. Cross-toolkit compatibility disabled.

WARNING: QDoc will not be compiled, probably because libclang could not be located. This means that you cannot build the Qt documentation.
```

Comment: Belated reply... and I don't know the answer to your question, but why don't you just copy the `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` directly into the `.exe` directory?  You'll have a known ( if old...) openssl and then you can use the stock qt libraries without recompiling everything?  I use Jake's [`copyToDestDir` found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984104/qmake-how-to-copy-a-file-to-the-output/10058744#10058744).

Comment: @RossRogers hi. So I was thinking of having a wrapper application that unpacks the SSL libraries to a location, then initializes the application PATH to include the libraries. However, the sounds overly complicated to get a single binary with SSL support enabled...not sure if I am going crazy shough

Comment: I don't think you have to change the `PATH` variable.  I haven't modified my `PATH` and my code does https requests that fail with TLS errors without those libraries.  I believe Windows looks for the DLL in the directory of the `*.exe` first and then it searches elsewhere.  I grab the dll's installed by `https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html` for the 64-bit version and then just copy them to the same directory as the `*.exe`.