# Facebook test apps not working on localhost

Tags: facebook, testing, localhost, facebook-apps

Since recently I can not test applications on localhost. There is no canvas url anymore to be set, only secure canvas url and it asks for https url. Even test apps do not have this option. So I have to buy another ssl and domain for testing pourposes only? If someone has the same problem or a solution please let me know. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you luschn for pointing that about self signed stuff out because just putting https://localhost will not work anymore.

It seems that facebook made some changes and that you can only test your apps on localhost if you create a self signed certificate with openssl tool. Then you can enter in secure canvas url something like https://localhost:3000/ and in app domains localhost and it seems to work. Other than creating selfsigned certificate I could not make it work on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Just put in `https://localhost` and accept the unsafe message in the browser, you don´t need to buy a certificate.

You can also use a self-signed certificate, as explained in other threads:

- [create a trusted self-signed SSL cert for localhost (for use with Express/Node)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397809/create-a-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-localhost-for-use-with-express-node)
- [How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost)