# Getting Node, Running on OS X, to Respond to HTTPS Connections

Tags: node.js, https

I have a small node program.

```
console.log("Program Started");
var http = require('http');

//Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {      
    console.log("Processing Request for URL" + request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.end("Hello World \n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000); 
console.log("Program Ended");
```

If I run this program on my MacBook and access the following URL, I see my Hello World message.

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

However, I'd like to have this URL responding to HTTPS connections as well.

```
https://localhost:8000/
```

How can I do this with NodeJS?

Can the native `http` library do this for me?  Or will I need Express?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can simply do It via https module :

1 you will have to create certificats , you can follow this auto here for macOS

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42298344/8395557