# How to run NUXT (npm run dev) with HTTPS in localhost?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nuxt.js

**EDIT:** Updated the text in general to keep it shorter and more concise.

I am trying to configure HTTPS when I run `npm run dev` so I can test MediaStream and alike locally (for which browsers require me to provide HTTPS).

I am trying to configure it through nuxt.config.js but without any success.

Here is my nuxt.config.js file:

```
import fs from "fs";
import pkg from "./package";

export default {
  mode: "spa",

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: pkg.description },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" },
    ],
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: "#fff" },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    "element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css",
    "@makay/flexbox/flexbox.min.css",
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    "@/plugins/element-ui",
    "@/plugins/vue-upload",
    "@/plugins/axios-error-event-emitter",
    "@/plugins/eventemitter2",
    "@/plugins/vue-awesome",
    "@/plugins/webrtc-adapter",
    "@/plugins/vue-browser-detect-plugin",
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa",
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
    baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "https://startupsportugal.com/api/v1" : "http://localhost:8080/v1",
  },

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    transpile: [/^element-ui/, /^vue-awesome/],

    filenames: {
      app: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? "[name].[hash].js" : "[chunkhash].js"),
      chunk: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? "[name].[hash].js" : "[chunkhash].js"),
    },

    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      // Run ESLint on save

      if (ctx.isClient) config.devtool = "#source-map";

      if (ctx.isDev) {
        config.devServer = {
          https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync("server.key"),
            cert: fs.readFileSync("server.crt"),
            ca: fs.readFileSync("ca.pem"),
          },
        };
      }

      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: "pre",
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: "eslint-loader",
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        });
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Also, here you can see my dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@makay/flexbox": "^3.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^2.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.4.11",
    "eventemitter2": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "nuxt": "^2.8.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "quagga": "^0.12.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-awesome": "^3.5.3",
    "vue-browser-detect-plugin": "^0.1.2",
    "vue-upload-component": "^2.8.20",
    "webrtc-adapter": "^7.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^0.0.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.15.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": ">=12.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.11.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": ">=2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": ">=22.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": ">=8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=0.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": ">=4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": ">=4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
```

However when I run `npm run dev` it still does not provide HTTPS, but does not provide any error output as well...

The output is exactly the same as if I didn't have the HTTPS configurations in nuxt.config.js:

```
$ npm run dev

> clothing-demo@1.0.0 dev /mnt/d/tralha/clothing-demo-app/frontend
> nuxt --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 3000


   ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                │
   │   Nuxt.js v2.8.1                               │
   │   Running in development mode (spa)            │
   │                                                │
   │   Listening on: http://192.168.126.241:3000/   │
   │                                                │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Preparing project for development                                                                                                                                                                                  14:30:34
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                                                                                                                                                                     14:30:35
✔ Builder initialized                                                                                                                                                                                                14:30:35
✔ Nuxt files generated
```

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: NUXT uses webpack. I'll add the dependencies and versions to the post

Comment: so you can use the https dev server to solve the problem? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhttps

Comment: I'm a bit lost. I added the following to my nuxt.config.js and tried "npm run dev" but nothing new happens... What am I missing?         if (ctx.isDev) {
        config.devServer = {
          http2: true,
        };
      }

Comment: why do you use http2 if you want https?

Comment: sorry, I mispelled, I meant https. Still that's not the cause, it had no effect at all... what am I missing?

Comment: can you show your webpackconfig for the https server pls?

Comment: Sure, I pastedbin it here: https://pastebin.com/SD2k77Ft

Comment: ok. I also removed the nginx part as it is not the core of the issue.

Comment: Have you follow the guid from the official website? https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-server/#example-using-https-configuration

Answer (score 86, accepted):

## HTTPS on local dev - NUXT style

Solution is described in NUXT documentation:

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-server/#example-using-https-configuration

This may be achieved with:

1. Go to project main dir;
2. Create private and public key;

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > server.key
chmod 400 server.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -key server.key -out server.crt
```

3. Add requirements to the top of the **nuxt.config.js**;

```
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'
```

4. Extend or add configuration of server in **nuxt.config.js**;

```
server: {
  https: {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.key')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.crt'))
  }
}
```

Comment: Having the same problem as OP. Followed these instructions to the letter but no luck.

Comment: This works for me, but how can I have this to only when I'm in development mode? This code is running in production and I don't want this.

Comment: @LincolnLemos try: server: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? {https: {...}} : {},

Comment: Just in case somebody need it, follow this instructions https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516812/4059304 and this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/163199/firefox-certificate-can-t-be-installed/163200#163200

Comment: I'm using localhost.run. It works and easy to setup. You don't need to do all those setup to make local authority to work with emulator/simulator.

Answer (score 17):

You must follow the doc spec here https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-server/#example-using-https-configuration, BUT you must add code in the `server/index.js` file, otherwise it won’t work at all.

So in the `server/index.js` add `const https = require('https')` at the top and replace :

```
app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
```

With

```
https.createServer(nuxt.options.server.https, app).listen(port, host);
```

And now it’s working!

Answer (score 16):

You can use `mkcert`

1. Install mkcert:

```sh
brew install mkcert
brew install nss # if you use Firefox
```

2. Add mkcert to your local root CAs:

```sh
mkcert -install
```

3. In your terminal, navigate to your site's root directory or whichever directory you'd like the certificates to be located at. And run:

```sh
mkcert localhost
```

4. Add the following to your `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
    server: {
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'localhost-key.pem')),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'localhost.pem'))
        }
    }
```

https://web.dev/how-to-use-local-https/

Comment: Easiest and most complete solution. Thank you. To add on this, ```const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
``` must be included at the top of the nuxt.config.js file.

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason you enable https just like Jan Doleczek said and you also make use of axios module, make sure to disable https like this in nuxt.config.js:

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://yourapi:8000',
    https:false,
  },
```

If you don't do that all your axios request will use https instead of https.

Comment: don't understand you last sentence. did you mean will use `http` instead of `https`?

Answer (score 2):

`Nuxt 3`:

> options.server from `nuxt.config` is not supported. You can use `--port, --host, --https, --ssl-cert` and `--ssl-key` instead.

[official docs](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/commands#development-server)

Something like this:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxi dev --host website.test --https --ssl-key key.pem --ssl-cert cert.pem --port 3000",
}
```

I hope I didn't lose `--` in example :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario to run local on `https` and share a `domain` or `subdomain` to share secured cookies for `Single Sign On` etc follow the below

Prerequisites

- openssl

  - if you're on Windows you can find `openssl.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`
- your .pfx certificate

  - including password if required

#### 1. Create .crt and .key files using openssl.exe

1.1 Create key

- `pkcs12 -in '[full-path-and-name-of-your].pfx' -nocerts -out '[full-path-and-name-to-create-the].key'`
- if prompted enter the password to open your .pfx

1.2 Create crt

- `pkcs12 -in '[full-path-and-name-of-your].pfx' -clcerts -nokeys -out '[full-path-and-name-to-create-the].crt'`
- Move the .key and .crt to the root of your source folder

[See more details here](https://www.markbrilman.nl/2011/08/howto-convert-a-pfx-to-a-seperate-key-crt-file/)

#### 2. Update `server` config likely in `nuxt.config.js`

- As other answers suggested follow the changes to set up https from [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-server#example-using-https-configuration)
- Enter the password used to at step 1 as the passphase value

```
  server: {
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '[key-file-name].key')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '[crt-file-name].crt')),
      passphrase: '[your password]'
    }
  }
```

#### 3. Create / Modify local build script to specify hostname

```
"dev": "nuxt --hostname subdmain.domain.com --port 8000"
```

Your local will now serve on https on that domain/subdomain and port e.g. `https://subdmain.domain.com:8000`

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers seems to work with `Nuxt 3` especially when the current version uses `defineNuxtConfig` as of version `3.2.3`. So I finally figure out how to do it with the current version.

`For Nuxt 3 and using TypeScript`

Install `fs-extra` and `@types/fs-extra`. Then inside nuxt.config.ts

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
import fs from "fs-extra";
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devServer: {
    host: "vios.uni.edu.my",
    port: 3000,
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync("../ssl/private.key").toString(),
      cert: fs.readFileSync("../ssl/cert.crt").toString(),
    },
  },
});
```

Since key `key` and `cert` required `string` type, we need to convert it to `string` via `toString()`

Comment: I get a "No default export found in imported module "fs-extra"." error, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to import it using an alias? `import * as fs from "fs-extra"`

Answer (score 0):

just run this cmd in you terminal:

```
 npm run dev -- --host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same thing. By [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/commands/dev) the following should work:

`nuxt.config.ts`:

```
devServer: {
    https:true,
    port: your PORT, // default: 3000
    host: 'your HOST' // deafult: 'localhost'
},
```

`.env`:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```