# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia - UNDEFINED in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, getusermedia

I have the following code which is to trigger the camera in Nuxt so I can capture an image, but I keep getting an error saying:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUserMedia')

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => {
  player.srcObject = stream;
});
```

This is in a method. I don't have anything in mounted.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: `navigator` is undefined because it initially runs on the server as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

Comment: Keep us informed if it works.

Comment: Will it only run on https? Thats what I read online. I am getting an undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @kissun for pointing me in the right direction.

I reckon this is a recurring issue because one cannot use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` in dev mode.

I added this function in `mounted` as suggested, however that did not work either.

After searching online, I discovered I had to use HTTPS in dev mode for it to ultimately work.

To do that, create your HTTPS certificate and key first, and then configure nuxt. Original, full, instructions can be found here [How to run NUXT (npm run dev) with HTTPS in localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966137/how-to-run-nuxt-npm-run-dev-with-https-in-localhost)

[image]

To setup nuxt, add this into your server object, in your nuxt.config.js file:

```
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

  server: {
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.key')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.crt'))
    }
  }
```

Now try using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

Comment: Camera, paying with a credit card or any sensitive things always require SSL indeed.