# HTTPS on localhost using NextJS + Express

Tags: reactjs, express, https, localhost, next.js

**System Information**

- [Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express): 4.16.4
- [NextJS](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/): 8.0.3
- [React](https://github.com/facebook/react): 16.8.4
- [ReactDOM](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-dom): 16.8.4

**Goal**

Serve the web application using SSL over HTTPS on localhost

**What has been done**

1. Created basic NextJS application using [Create Next App](https://github.com/segmentio/create-next-app)
2. Generated a certificate and key using OpenSSL and moved it into the project directory
3. Added the Express dependency
4. Configured the app to use express inside `server.js`
5. Changed script to use the `server.js` inside `package.json` scripts.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const port = 3000;

const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./certificates/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certificates/cert.pem')
};

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(port, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('> Ready on http://localhost: ' + port);
    });
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

**Extra Information**

The app currently works when initialized using `yarn dev`. I have tried to serve the app over https using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42298344/3256783) but I was unable to figure out how to apply this to my current setup using NextJS.

I spent a lot of time researching the web how to apply this solution but have not yet found a way on how to make this work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use ngrok, very easy to use tool to make local port available online via https. Method explained here: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/run-next-js-app-locally-in-https/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to use the `createServer` method of `https` module.

```
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { parse } = require('url');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const next = require('next');

const port = 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const httpsOptions = {
  key: readFileSync('./certificates/key.pem'),
  cert: readFileSync('./certificates/cert.pem')
};

app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    createServer(httpsOptions, (req, res) => {
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }).listen(port, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`> Ready on https://localhost:${port}`);
    })
  });
```

Comment: This works for me, Thank you @Tibi02! Previously I was trying to use the `createServer` method but I was not using it correctly, so I am glad you managed to give me a good example.

Comment: Where is the express?

Comment: how to integrate https on express server?

Answer (score 9):

Other answer seemed to just drop express... Found a solution after some difficulty with both server code and certificate so hopefully can save someone else the trouble!

First of all, solid advice for creating localhost certificate here:
https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Secondly, simple code that offers HTTP/HTTPS with next js and express:

```
const next = require('next');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const ports = {
  http: 3080,
  https: 3443
}
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const server = express();  

const options = { 
  key: fs.readFileSync('localhost.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('localhost.crt'), 
};

app.prepare().then(() => {           
  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)    
  });
  http.createServer(server).listen(ports.http);
  https.createServer(options, server).listen(ports.https);
});
```

It is worth noting that one could omit or redirect either port.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
Run your dev server and get their http port.

Step 2:
Run `local-ssl-proxy` with your desire ports, in target parameter must be the current dev server port.

```
npx local-ssl-proxy --source 3001 --target 3000
```

Step 3: Visit your brand new HTTPS service
https://localhost:3001 or use your IP inside your LAN https://192.168.1.21:3001

Answer (score 0):

Below work for me very well for next server with https;

Using this official documentation of node js https module [Creating HTTPS Server](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener)

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

const httpsOptions = {
    pfx: readFileSync('./certificates/AMB.pfx'),
    passphrase: 'Testabc$'
  };

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(httpsOptions, (req, res) => {    
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
        const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

        if (pathname === '/login') {
            app.render(req, res, '/login', query)
        } else {
            handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
        }
    }).listen(port, err => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Ready on https://localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Our straightforward, switchable implementation:

```
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');
const next = require('next');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const HTTPS = true;
const server = HTTPS
  ? https.createServer(
      {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './server.key')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './server.cert')),
      },
      app
    )
  : http.createServer({}, app);

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const nextApp = next({ dev });
const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  app.get('/api/something', (req, res) => {
    res.json({});
  });

  // ...

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return nextHandler(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http${HTTPS ? 's' : ''}://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

next.js 13.5.1 released today has built-in experimental support for HTTPS dev server using the `--experimental-https` flag: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v13.5.1