# Why HTTPS not working in AWS EC2 with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, openssl

I want to enable https in AWS EC2 windows instance.

I did the nodejs(my server side) config using the  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397809/create-a-trusted-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-localhost-for-use-with-express-node.

My config file is as below,

```
[req]
    distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = XX
ST = XX
L = XXXXXX
O = XXX
OU = XXXX 
CN = XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080
DNS.2 = XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080
DNS.3 = XX.XX.XXX.XX
```

Generated the certificate and key using the able config.

In AWS EC2 machine https//:localhost:8080 works as expected but https://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080 not working. Also https://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080 not able to access from outside internet. Early same IP with HTTP works fine in local and outside.

My AWS In bound rules as follows

[image]

Ports 8080 and 3306 already enabled in the EC2 instance.

Getting below error
[image]

Comment: what error do you get from outside access ? Does it perform TCP 3 way handshake ?

Comment: Please find the image attached just now