# ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error on HTTPS server

Tags: https, openssl, ssl-certificate, angular-pwa

I am trying to host an angular app on my local machine on https for it to access from my iPad.

I need a secure https connection to be established, but I am getting `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error.

I have created an SSL certificate and using it as per this [post](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397809/create-a-trusted-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-localhost-for-use-with-express-node/26815269&ved=2ahUKEwibuJS4upjjAhVi7HMBHVBMA58QFjABegQIBRAS&usg=AOvVaw0_3cK1R_mglwV4KZ03foHP) .

Comment: And what is the Common Name in your certificate?

Comment: I have aded full computer name from system settings (windows 10)

Comment: And it does contain a backslash character, like `IniTechDomain\WS03451` ?

Comment: Nope, ___. ___. com

Comment: I think you should find out what the problem is with the Common Name and fix it.

Comment: that's what I don't know actually. Is there any way to mention proxy settings in conf file while generating certificate?