# Angular Azure AD Callback. After authentication, getting Cannot Post callback

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory

I am calling azure ad from angular. I get redirected to the azure ad portal and was able to successfully authenticate. Afterwards, it redirects back to the web client but in debug mode, I am see a blank page

the URL is https://localhost:4200/auth/callback#id_token='jasdfsdflkjfasafiow ....

the page is blank and states  Cannot Post /auth/callback

In my app-routing.module.ts, I have

{ path: 'auth/callback', component: CallbackComponent }

In my callback.component.ts

There is no code in the constructor or ngOnIt

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a invalid cert that was causing this error. I followed the steps in the link below and it went away

[create a trusted self-signed SSL cert for localhost (for use with Express/Node)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397809/create-a-trusted-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-localhost-for-use-with-express-node)