# How to handle moving of self-signed SSL/TLS .pem files with Webpack for dev/prod environments?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, webpack, pem

I have lost almost couple of weeks trying to find the answer to this and to no avail. I quit trying to use `webpack-dev-middleware` to handle server refreshing so I am back to using `nodemon` to handle restarting my backend during development phase.

The project structure is as follows (it's mostly basic, just trying to get the general out of the way):

- /

  - dev/ (output)
  - prod/ (output)
  - src/

    - index.ts
    - tls/

      - key.pem
      - cert.pem
      - configuration.ts

`configuration.ts`

```
import fs from "fs";

export const configuration = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem"),
  passphrase: "passphrase"
};
```

As I have mentioned in the title, I am trying to handle moving of said `.pem` files to my development and production output directories with `webpack`. I have created both of these files (with some passphrase) by using this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

These two files (key and certificate), and the TypeScript files that is reading these key and cert files. As these two are required to have HTTPS on the server side, I am trying to have them moved to `dev/` and `prod/` directories (depending which environment I am working in of course), and I want the files to be read there after I start the server.

This was all doable without `webpack`, by just regularly using `node index.server.js` and starting the server file which is reading the key and cert files, but as I am trying to force myself to use `typescript` everywhere, I am also in need of modules which in turn require `webpack` and it creates this problem. I am new to backend and I am trying to use some good practices to handle login, hence I am trying to resolve this TLS/SSL issue to have cookie login with some best-practices flags.

I have tried few things with `file-loader`, but no luck, and searching for this issue's solution led me nowhere mostly. If you require more information let me know I will do my best to answer, and thanks in advance.

EDIT: After I am trying to `console.log` the `configuration` variable from the SSL/TLS configuration file, this is what `webpack` assembles in the end:

```
var configuration = {
    key: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
    cert: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.readFileSync("./cert.pem"),
    passphrase: "passphrase"
};
```

My Webpack configuration(s) - I have `common`, `dev` and `prod` files, here are the `common` and `dev` for example:

`webpack.common.js`

```
const webpackNodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals"),
  configuration = {
    target: "node",
    entry: {
      index: "./src/index.ts"
    },
    externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          include: /src/,
          loader: "ts-loader"
        }
      ]
    }
  };

module.exports = configuration;
```

`webpack.dev.js`

```
const path = require("path"),
  merge = require("webpack-merge"),
  common = require("./webpack.common"),
  webpackShellPlugin = require("webpack-shell-plugin"),
  configuration = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "source-map",
    watch: true,
    plugins: [
      new webpackShellPlugin({
        onBuildEnd: ["npm run dev:run"]
      })
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dev"),
      filename: "[name].server.js"
    }
  });

module.exports = configuration;
```

`package.json`

```
    "dev:start": "webpack --config ./configurations/webpack.dev.js",
    "dev:run": "nodemon -r dotenv/config ./dev/index.server.js",
    "prod:start": "webpack --config ./configurations/webpack.prod.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem I believe. I have used a different way to generate SSL/TLS key/certificate as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397809/create-a-trusted-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-localhost-for-use-with-express-node).

After that I managed to figure out I was missing some essential Webpack configuration, since the process was figuring `__dirname` meant root somehow, so I added this into the configuration:

```
node: {
  __dirname: false,
  __filename: false
}
```

The app is now successfully serving production and development environments.