# How to configure CORS middlware in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, next.js, cors

Still new to working with web applications, APIs, and HTTP stuff.

I'm working with two apps

- an ASP.NET Core Web API that uses https (server `https://localhost:7086` and `http://localhost:5234`)
- a Nextjs app that uses the [Page Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages) (another server: localhost:3000)

The requests from my frontend typically require the `Authorization` header for the JWT. Additionally, `auth/login/` and `auth/register/` set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`

When my middleware in `Program.cs` is structured like this:

*Middleware 1:*

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseProblemDetails();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My browser tools tells me that I have the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5234/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

But, when my middleware is configured like this:

*Middleware 2*

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseProblemDetails();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("MyPolicy"); // UseCors before UseHttpsRedirection and no UseRouting

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My React app works perfectly.

**Note:** I have previously configured the CORS middleware to accept any and all requests, so it shouldn't be a problem:

```cs
builder.Services.AddCors(policy => 
    policy.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", build =>
        {
            build.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
```

You might be thinking: *Just don't do the thing that doesn't work*. And I kinda want to ignore it, too! But based on the [Microsoft documentation on Cors middle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> `UseCors` must be placed after `UseRouting` and before `UseAuthorization`. This is to ensure that CORS headers are included in the response for both authorized and unauthorized calls.

So why is this happening - and how can I fix it?

**Additional question**: I initially wanted to use React Server Components with Next.js 13's [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app). But even when my middleware was configured like *Middleware 2*, I was still getting an error and it wouldn't work. I ended up abandoning that idea and went for the [Page Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages) instead.

Why doesn't it work? Am I allowed to do SSR if I fetch data from an API that's from an *external* server?

Comment: you use http instead of https, thats why microsoft guide does not work. The message "Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request." tells you that - browser makes a call, but receives 301 redirect which results into CORS error. you have to use https endpoints locally. if you don't have them configured - you will have to install dev certificates

Comment: second question must be posted separately along with the code

Comment: @YehorAndrosov Thank you for your insight. How can I install dev certificates so I can use Https endpoints locally? I'm on a Windows machine using Next js.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397809/create-a-trusted-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-localhost-for-use-with-express-node

Comment: not familiar with nextjs but answers there should be close enough to help