# Can openssl.exe be used without installing it?

Tags: windows, openssl

Running `openssl.exe req` without installing it runs into this error:

> Can't open C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\SSL/openssl.cnf for
>   reading, No such file or directory 54944:error:02001003:system
>   library:fopen:No such
>   process:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:72:fopen('C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\SSL/openssl.cnf','r') 54944:error:2006D080:BIO
>   routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:79:

Is there a way to tell openssl to look for this file elsewhere, e.g. locally?
The use case is to bundle openssl with an application without having to run an installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it in [one of the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15416214/154766), the answer is:

`openssl.exe req -config yourconfigfile.cnf`