# openssl_pkey_export and "cannot get key from parameter 1"

Tags: php, openssl, rsa

I need to use openssl within my php project, so I created a test php page using openssl. However, I keep getting these errors and I am not sure why. openssl is enabled.

> Warning: openssl_pkey_export() [function.openssl-pkey-export]: cannot get key from parameter 1 in C:\wamp\www\opensslsample\index.php on line 18
>
> Warning: openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\opensslsample\index.php on line 21

```
<?php
 //echo phpinfo();

   $privateKey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
'private_key_bits' => 1024,
'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
));

openssl_pkey_export($privateKey, $privkey,"123");

$pubkey=openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);
$pubkey=$pubkey["key"];
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at the following explanation. It might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866994/openssl-wont-create-private-keys/22847076#22847076

Answer (score 38):

This may help if you are on windows:

1. Click on the START button
2. Click on CONTROL PANEL
3. Click on SYSTEM AND SECURITY
4. Click on SYSTEM
5. Click on ADVANCED SYSTEM SETTINGS
6. Click on ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
7. Under "System Variables" click on "NEW"
8. Enter the "Variable name" OPENSSL_CONF
9. Enter the "Variable value".

`Wamp` - `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\openssl.cnf`

`Xampp` - `C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf`

10. Click "OK" and close all the windows and RESTART your computer.

The OPENSSL should be correctly working.

Comment: The 10th step is crucial. I tried a lot of solutions that I found on stackoverflow and other blogs, and none of them mentioned that you need to RESTART your computer. I spend 3 hours trying make this work, but only worked after I restarted my PC.

Comment: @Ansari It worked! I am using PHP built in web server on Windows10, so I added the following to system vriables: C:\php\extras\ssl\openssl.cnf, then I restarted windows, that is all, thanks.

Comment: 10. just restart Apache?

Comment: great it worked! for those who're working on xampp your env variable should look like ```C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf``` instead

Answer (score 1):

Check `openssl_error_string`. My guess is that your openssl.cnf file is missing or something.

Alternatively, you could use [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), to generate keys. eg.

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

extract($rsa->createKey());

echo "$privatekey<br />$publickey";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I extract from [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) to fix it in [jose-jwt lib](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose/blob/master/src/Factory/JWKFactory.php) and it worked, you need this several changes:

```
<?php

$config = array();
$config['config'] = dirname(__FILE__) . '/openssl.cnf';

$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
  'private_key_bits' => 1024,
  'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
) + $config);

openssl_pkey_export($privateKey, $privkey, "123", $config);
```

And this minimalist config file:

```
# minimalist openssl.cnf file for use with phpseclib

HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

[ v3_ca ]
```

Called `openssl.cnf`. With all this it should work well.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP needs to find your openssl.cnf. The best way to achieve this is to add the directory location of it in the PATH environment variable.