# PrestaShop error "Create file parameters"

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I face "Create file parameters" error while installing prestashop 8.1. can anyone suggest any solution?

I have asked this question in the prestashop community. but i did not found a solution there.
I expect a good solution in here.

Comment: I faced the same issue, check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272809/openssl-pkey-export-and-cannot-get-key-from-parameter-1, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. While debugging, I saw that there is some problem with SSL.
I found out that the OpenSSL needed to be installed for PrestaShop to be installed.
I have downloaded and instaled one from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html, restarted WAMPServer and then everithing was OK.

Regards,
Tomo

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i changed php version of wamp from 8 to 7 and it works!