# openssl create key error php

Tags: php, openssl, key

I tried this following code

```
// Create the keypair
$res=openssl_pkey_new();

// Get private key
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privatekey);

// Get public key
$publickey=openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$publickey=$publickey["key"];
```

but i get this error

> Warning: openssl_pkey_export(): cannot get key from parameter 1 in ...
>   Warning: openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...

I already uncomment `extension=php_openssl.dll` my php.ini file. and openssl supported when i checked in phpinfo(). short of confused. i don't know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check what message the following produces.

```
var_dump(openssl_error_string());
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php

Comment: thankyou for your answer and this is the result 

string(51) "error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process"

Answer (score 0):

`$res` is supposed to be a resource. This is the return of `openssl_pkey_new()`. See the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php). But it can also be *FALSE*.

Errors like the one you are seeing often mean that the function that creates the resource, here `openssl_pkey_new()`, failed. As the documentation says,

> Returns a resource identifier for the pkey on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

So you need to check the error. I am not familiar, but `openssl_error_string` looks promising.

**EDIT In Responce**: SO question [openssl-not-working-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558321/openssl-not-working-on-windows). This appears to be your problem. The processes can not find your openSSL config file. Read this [OpenSLL Configuration guide by PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php)

Suggestion, Use a while loop to read all the error messages, as described in the link. If it is the same error follow the instructions.

Comment: thanks for answering and this is the result

string(51) "error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process"

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have better luck with [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) tbh. eg.

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

extract($rsa->createKey());

echo "$publickey<br />$privatekey";
?>
```

That creates a 1024-bit key by default. If you need to customize it above and beyond the default settings lmk.