# XAMPP 3.2.1 and typo3 6.2 OpenSSL not working

Tags: openssl, xampp, typo3

I do have the following problem. Trying to install typo3 6.2 on my local machine under xampp 3.2.1
Installer tells me "PHP OpenSSL extension not working"

What I've done so far:

- checked extension=php_openssl.dll in my php/bin
- "sysext", "rsaauth" and "saltedpasswords" are in my typo3 folder
- apache ssl_module is running
- put ssl in the system variables

I've also tried a downgrade to OpenSSL 0.9.8, but still getting the error. Btw, I've restarted xampp after every edit.

I'm running xampp on Windows 8.1

Comment: Did you check the PHP error log?

Comment: No errors in there. I don't get any errors. PHP Info tells me that SSL is up and running but Typo3 tells me it isn't. I'll try WAMP instead, maybe that'll help.

Comment: `phpinfo` only tells you if the module is loaded, while TYPO3 actually checks if it can be used to create keys. Therefore you need to check if all directories are writeable, etc.

Comment: Changed everything to 777, still not working. I might give up and change to online development :(

Comment: did you check the tipps on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558321/openssl-not-working-on-windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the exception linked above:

Windows 7 and Wamp

- Activate the PHP module openssl
- Assuming you installed wamp into
  `C:\wamp`, openssl.exe is found into
  `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin`
- Add an environment variable
  `OPENSSL_CONF` with value
  `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\openssl.cnf`
- Either set
  `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['binSetup']` as described above or append
  `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin` to the environment variable `PATH`
  (will work for every PHP script not only TYPO3)
- Restart wamp

Answer (score 0):

On typo3 6.2.7on win7 XAMPP 1.8.3 The openSSL error's solution was to create C:\ openssl-1.0.1i-win32\ssl folder and put E:\Portables\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf into it. I got a direction about it from a german website.

How I found it out(just in case versions change) In the shell on XAMPP control panel, openssl command gives “WARNING: can't open config file: E:/Portables/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf”. But adding the file there does not help. I added and removed the file

Add ;E:\Portables\xampp\apache\bin to PATH environment variable (System properties -> Advanced). Run command openssl on a CMD window(not XMPP shell), the message “WARNING: can't open config file: c:/openssl-1.0.1i-win32/ssl/openssl.cnf” comes. Add the file there The addition to environment variable PATH can be removed now.

Adding OPENSSL_CONF also did not work for me

Comment: I had the same problem and c:/openssl-1.0.1i-win32/ssl/openssl.cnf was for me the solution. However I detected by running the openssl.exe in the Apache bin directory, so it showed that openssl.cnf is missing in that path. Therefore I recommand you to run openssl.exe direcly in cmd to see exactly what says it.

Comment: Once again I tried and found that it is not necessary to copy openssl.cnf to c:/openssl-1.0.1i-win32/ssl. You can just make an environmen or user variable OPENSSL_CONF. The path to openssl.cnf should be the value for the variable - in my case C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf or for WAMP as @pgampe mentioned. Now you should first stop Apache in the XAMPP/WAMP control panel and then - VERY IMPORTANT!!! - you should exit the control panel it self as well - click on Quit. Open the panel and restart Apache. It should work properly. Now you can remove c:/openssl-1.0.1i-win32/ssl/openssl.cnf.

Answer (score -1):

Check your httpd.conf, and try to disable the SSL there, because PHP has its own ssl.dll

Should look like this:

```
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so   

...

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
# starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
# but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
#<IfModule ssl_module>
#SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
#SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
#</IfModule>
```

Found here: http://www.typo3forum.net/forum/typo3-installation-updates/74548-openssl-not-working-installation-xampp-aktiviert-php-ini.html

If this is not working, try to follow this wiki post:

http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1318283565

Comment: First thing has no effect, second could work, but as I can't install, I don't even have those files which I should edit :(

Comment: The HTTP SSL part has nothing to do with the PHP SSL.