# Error 0x2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib with PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, openssl

I am getting the following error while trying to load my private key by simple way. This is my code.

```
public function loadPrivateKey($fileName, $password = null){
        if(!is_file($fileName))
            throw new SignException('Private key not found', SignException::KEY_NOT_FOUND);

        $fileContent = file_get_contents($fileName);
        if(!is_null($password))
            $this->prvKey = openssl_get_privatekey($fileContent, $password);
        else
            $this->prvKey = openssl_get_privatekey($fileContent);

        if(!empty(openssl_error_string()))
            throw new SignException('OpenSSL Error: '.openssl_error_string());

        if(!is_resource($this->prvKey))
            throw new SignException('Private key is not resourse', SignException::EXTERNAL_ERROR);
    }
```

`openssl_error_string()` returns `error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib`.

I enabled OpenSSL in my `php.ini` with `extension=php_openssl.dll`.

What could be the problem? How do I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenSSL not working on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558321/openssl-not-working-on-windows).

Comment: Also see [OpenSSL and error in reading openssl.conf file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11241669/608639).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `openssl_get_privatekey()` is an alias for [`openssl_pkey_get_private()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php). This function takes two arguments; the first is either a filename in URI format, or the contents of a PEM-formatted private key. The second is a passphrase.

The error you're getting indicates an error trying to read a file; typically the file in question is [included in the error message](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/bio/bss_file.c#L170), so it's possible you're only including part of the error here. Since you're not reading the file with OpenSSL, the most likely culprit is the OpenSSL configuration file; the system needs to be told where to look for it.

- Right click on My Computer and go into Properties
- On the Advanced tab, click the Environment Variables button
- Create a new entry under System Variables
- The Variable name should be "OPENSSL_CONF"
- The Variable value should be the full path to the file
- Restart the computer

Environment variables can also be set from [within your PHP code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php), though it will need to be added to all your code, so may not be preferable. Also, as mentioned, you can open the key file directly from the function call; here's what I'd suggest trying:

```
<?php
public function loadPrivateKey($fileName, $password = "") {
    // I just used the value from my system here
    putenv("OPENSSL_CONF=C:\\OpenSSL\\bin\\openssl.cfg");
    if (!is_readable($fileName)) {
        throw new SignException("Private key not found or not readable", SignException::KEY_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    $fileName = "file://$fileName";

    $this->prvKey = openssl_get_privatekey($fileName, $password);

    if (!empty(openssl_error_string())) {
        throw new SignException("OpenSSL error: " . openssl_error_string());
    }

    if (!is_resource($this->prvKey)) {
        throw new SignException("Private key is not resource", SignException::EXTERNAL_ERROR);
    }
}
```