# openssl_pkey_get_details cause internal server error

Tags: php, apache, php-openssl

I make some code to generate public and private code. It was working ok on one machine, but on other server it is causing "Internal Server Error".

```
private function keyGen()   
{
    if(is_file($this::pubK_path) )
        exec("rm ".$this::pubK_path);
    if(is_file($this::privK_path) )
        exec("rm ".$this::privK_path);

    $config = array(
        "digest_alg" => "sha512",
        "private_key_bits" => 512,
        "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
    );

    // Create the private and public key
    $this->key = openssl_pkey_new($config);

    $pubkey=openssl_pkey_get_details($this->key);
    $this->pubkey=$pubkey["key"];

    $privK=null;
    openssl_pkey_export($this->key, $privK,$this->pass);
    file_put_contents($this::privK_path, $privK);
    file_put_contents($this::pubK_path, $this->pubkey);
}
```

Sadly I didn't find any information about this error in any log. I only find that it is caused by this line:

```
$pubkey=openssl_pkey_get_details($this->key);
```

Key is generated properly - when I deleted openssl_pkey_get_details, private key was saved in file.

Any ideas what is wrong, or other method to get public key?

Comment: Did you tried something more? Did you find the error with the `openssl_error_string()` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Sadly I didn't find any information about this error in any log.

You can use [`openssl_error_string()`](http://php.net/openssl_error_string) to find out what is  `openssl_pkey_new()` returning, you should see a `false` or any other `OpenSSL` error (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282507/why-does-openssl-pkey-new-fail#4282885)). Like:

```
<?php
// lets assume you just called an openssl function that failed
while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
    echo $msg . "<br />\n";
?>
```

Then it should be easy to find the problem (you can update this thread with the error).

Hope it helps!